# How to get image properties in tooltip

Tags: wpf, image, tooltip

I have one task to get image type, dimensions and size in Tooltip. I tried Using this code. I got Image url , Not able to fetch Image property in ToolTip..

```
 <Image Source="{Binding Path=UriSource}" Stretch="Fill" Width="100" Height="120">
    <Image.ToolTip>
         <ToolTip Content="{Binding}"/>
    </Image.ToolTip>
</Image>
```

How to get image Dimensions in tooltip WPF?

Comment: Note that `Source="{Binding Path=UriSource}"` is wrong in the first place. `Path=UriSource` indicates that the binding source object is already a BitmapImage. Your Binding however creates another BitmapFrame by built-in type conversion from Uri to ImageSource. The Binding should simply look like this: `Source="{Binding}"`

Comment: Urisource is collection of bitmap images.

Comment: Sure, since UriSource is a property of a single BitmapImage in a collection, you could simply do `Source="{Binding}"`. That said, it is not at all clear what "image type, dimensions and size" are supposed to be here. While dimensions and size seems to mean the same thing, image type is unclear. Do you perhaps mean the BitmapImage's PixelWidth and PixelHeight?

Comment: using given answer able to show width in image tag. not to fetch original size of the image

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since your Binding source object seems to be a BitmapSource, you could directly bind to its properties, e.g. its PixelWidth and PixelHeight:

```
<Image Source="{Binding}" Width="100" Height="120">
    <Image.ToolTip>
        <ToolTip Content="{Binding}">
            <ToolTip.ContentTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>
                    <StackPanel>
                        <TextBlock Text="{Binding PixelWidth, StringFormat=Width: {0}}"/>
                        <TextBlock Text="{Binding PixelHeight, StringFormat=Height: {0}}"/>
                    </StackPanel>
                </DataTemplate>
            </ToolTip.ContentTemplate>
        </ToolTip>
    </Image.ToolTip>
</Image>
```

Or shorter:

```
<Image Source="{Binding}" Width="100" Height="120">
    <Image.ToolTip>
        <StackPanel>
            <TextBlock Text="{Binding PixelWidth, StringFormat=Width: {0}}"/>
            <TextBlock Text="{Binding PixelHeight, StringFormat=Height: {0}}"/>
        </StackPanel>
    </Image.ToolTip>
</Image>
```

---

In case the Binding source is not a BitmapSource, but for instance just an image file Uri or a path string, you may bind to the (automatically created) BitmapSource object in the Image's `Source` property like this:

```
<Image Source="{Binding}" Width="160" Height="120">
    <Image.ToolTip>
        <ToolTip DataContext="{Binding PlacementTarget.Source,
                                       RelativeSource={RelativeSource Self}}">
            <StackPanel>
                <TextBlock Text="{Binding PixelWidth, StringFormat=Width: {0}}"/>
                <TextBlock Text="{Binding PixelHeight, StringFormat=Height: {0}}"/>
            </StackPanel>
        </ToolTip>
    </Image.ToolTip>
</Image>
```

Answer (score 1):

If you want to get the properties of the parent control, you have to set the `DataContext` of the `ToolTip`:

```
    <Image Source="face-monkey.png" Width="60">
        <Image.ToolTip>
            <ToolTip DataContext="{Binding Path=PlacementTarget, RelativeSource={x:Static RelativeSource.Self}}">
                <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
                    <Label Content="Width:" FontWeight="Bold"/>
                    <Label Content="{Binding Width}"/>
                </StackPanel>
            </ToolTip>
        </Image.ToolTip>
    </Image>
```

[image: monkey]

Comment: I have 100 images. loading from web. i don't know the width and height.